# ValueConverter - binding to self

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I need to bind a label to a composite value - made up of a couple of values in the model. I'm trying to use a ValueConverter to do so, but I can't figure out how to pass the object itself to the ValueConverter. Here's my code:
in XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
         x:Class="MyApp.SavedDetailsPage">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
          <local:DetailsConverter x:Key="detailsCvt" />
      </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  ...
    <Label Text="{Binding ???, Converter={StaticResource detailsCvt}}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Gray" />
  ...
```

in DetailsConverter.cs:

```cs
class DetailsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel)value;
        return (myModel.FirstName + " " + myModel.LastName);
    }
    ...
```

I tried using '.' for binding to self, but that didn't work.

I found a way around it by adding a .This property to MyModel, that gives access to the object itself, so I can pass 'This' in the XAML binding, but not sure if that's the best way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your BindingContext being set? Are you using a MVVM framework?

Comment: where do you set Page's BindingContext?

Comment: Another workaround could be to introduce a property on your model which does the composition for you

Comment: @StevenThewissen: I'm setting the ItemsSource on a ListView

Comment: @GeraldVersluis: I thought about that, but I'd like to keep my model clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to bind to the ViewModel, you can use one of the following syntax

```xml
{Binding}
{Binding .}
{Binding Path="."}
```